# Boost::IntrusiveList with Shared Pointers

Tags: c++, boost, event-handling, shared-ptr, intrusive-containers

So I'm writing an event handling system using FastDelegate<> and the boost library. I need to setup a Queue of shared pointers to event data as well as a list of FastDelegate> for listeners. So here's the problem.

Intrusive list and queue don't allow shared_ptr or even constant references which makes my code cause compile time errors. Anyway that I can do this?

It seems safest to hand off a shared ptr to delegates that way the event stays around until everyone is truly done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q.** Intrusive list and queue don't allow shared_ptr

No problem:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53a7fe6d5b0ad20b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

struct Event {};

struct Node : boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<> {
    boost::shared_ptr<Event> event { new Event };
};

typedef boost::intrusive::list<Node> event_list;

int main() {
    std::vector<Node> nodes(10);

    event_list pending;
    pending.push_back(nodes[3]);
    pending.push_back(nodes[7]);
}
```

From the fact that you expected (?) `intrusive::list<T>` to work for `T = shared_ptr<...>` tells me that you want a simple `std::list` (or just a `std::vector`) instead.

> or even constant references

Constant references are no problem either. Did you want to use `shared_ptr<const Event>`? Because that's a good option if you're sharing the event with multiple parties.